# UTF-8 Encoding and decoding issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, encoding, utf-8

I'm having a problem with converting text from and to UTF-8 encoding. Here I have byte array,

```
byte[] c = new byte[] { 1, 2, 200 };
```

I'm converting it to UTF-8 string and back to byte array,

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(c));
```

According to my understand what i should be expecting from this is an array with 3 bytes. right? But here's what I'm getting.

```
byte[5] { 1, 2, 239, 191, 189 }
```

What's the reason for this?
I understand the `239, 191, 189` combination is called `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` in [UTF-8 Specials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)).

Also this is part of a bigger problem.

Comment: Why are you doing that? { 1, 2, 3, 200 } is *not* text encoded as UTF-8. If you're aiming to propagate arbitrary binary data, use base64. It sounds like you're not "converting text" - you're converting binary data.

Answer (score 2):

Not all sequences of bytes are valid UTF-8. It seems that your array (1, 2, 200) is invalid in UTF-8 (that's why this special error character is added)

MSDN says about Encoding.UTF8:

> It returns a UTF8Encoding object that provides a Unicode byte order
>   mark (BOM). To instantiate a UTF8 encoding that doesn't provide a BOM,
>   call any overload of the UTF8Encoding constructor.

1) There are no BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your example.

2) 200 - a leading byte. It must be followed by enough continuation bytes